# How to make the binding work on a text entry in a frame?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
  frame=Frame(root)
  frame.place(x=55,y=50)
  L1=Label(frame,text="1",font=("calibri")).pack()
  frame1=Frame(root)
  frame1.place(x=70,y=50)
  E1 = tk.Entry(frame1, width=30, bd=4).pack()
  E1.bind('<Return>', lambda event, arg=(0): answer(event, arg))
```

I put an entry widget on a frame but the binding on it does not work. It says:

E1.bind('', lambda event, arg=(0): answer(event, arg))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tk.Entry(frame1, width=30, bd=4).pack()` returns `None` so `E1` is of `NoneType`, hence the error. If you do

```
E1 = tk.Entry(frame1, width=30, bd=4)
E1.pack()
E1.bind('<Return>', lambda event, arg=(0): answer(event, arg))
```

the binding should work.